# Slow performance with date comparison with number datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sqldatatypes, sql-optimization

```
Select * from table
WHERE to_date(a.date_key, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN to_date('&date3', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date('&date4', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Here a.date_key is a number and I am changing the format. But applying the above process makes it slow performance wise.

Is it right way to do it or we can make it better in a different way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is the table partitioned by date_key. If so then applying a to_date on a partition key would have preempted partition pruning from occuring.

Comment: date_key in what number format ? is it ddmmyyyy ? if it is in yyyymmdd then i think you try relational operator with the range you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the best way.  Assuming `date_key` is a string of the form YYYY-MM-DD, then do the comparisons as strings:

```
WHERE a.date_key BETWEEN '&date3' AND '&date4'
```

The comparison will be accurate and Oracle can use indexes, partitions, and statistics on `date_key`.

This begs the question why you have a key at all instead of using a `date` data type.  But that is another issue.

Comment: OP said it's number, not string. And it might be true, since it can be really converted to date using 'yyyy-mm-dd' format mask: select to_date(20200130,'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual

Comment: @xt.and.r . . . In that case, pass in numbers that look like the string, say 20200707.

Comment: I'd avoid implicit conversions :)

Comment: @xt.and.r . . . I would as well.  The parameters passed in should match the type of `date_key`.

Answer (score 1):

As your number column is in YYYY-MM-DD format, You can directly use them as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
 WHERE
    A.DATE_KEY BETWEEN '&date3' AND '&date4'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here a.date_key is a number

If it's really number, you can just simply use

```
where a.date_key between 19810101 and 19891231
```